# Unexpected result from bin()

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

why i get this result. Please describe problem.

Python 3.7 PyCharm 2018.3.5

```
def byte_operation(a, b):
    a = int(bin(a)[2:])
    b = int(bin(b)[2:])
    print(~a)
    print(~b)
    return
```

I run `byte_operation(45, 45)` and get:

```
-101102
-101102
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" and "Introduce the problem before you post any code". As well, please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: What's the result you expected?

Comment: I expect - 101101 but have - 101102

Comment: What `a` and `b` are you passing to the function? You need [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] — otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk: If you want `-101101`, use `-`, not `~`. The latter flips bits (in the weird quasi-two's complement system Python's bitwise ops use), it doesn't negate, so it's equivalent to negating, then subtracting one (where negation is equivalent to flipping all the bits, then adding one).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `a = 45` and `b = 45`.
`bin(45)` equals `'0b101101'` in binary system. If you remove first two letters from this string (using `[2:]`) and cast it to int you will get integer value (`int('101101') == 101101`).

Comment: Yes, i understand that but why python print 101102?

Comment: For integers ~a is equivalent of (-a) - 1. Thats because you make bitwise negation on two's complement numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result. When you apply `~` to an integer, [you are performing *bitwise negation*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations). In two's complement notation, `~x == -x - 1`. Therefore, `~101101 = -101101 - 1 = -101102`.

Comment: Ty, try at morning